# Program works with map() but raises TypeError with pool.map()

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I do have a program, which has not been used for quite a while, but it has been used and worked already. It uses multiprocessing as the same task has to be done for different data many times.

I now touched the program to add a new parameter, tested it and notices that it comes up with an error. Also the earlier (version controlled) version comes up with the same error. The full error looks like this:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 811, in __bootstrap_inner
            self.run()
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 764, in run
            self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
           put(task)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

That is all. it does not say much to me, to be honest. While trying to debug this, i came to the idea to try using the normal `map()` instead of the pooled version `pool.map`. The script then runs fine.

I can not come up with a minimal example, which reproduces the error, but I can come up with an example, where everything works fine, just as expected:

```
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def do_work(x, y, z):
     time.sleep(random.random() * 2)
     print x + y + z

def do_one(arguments):
    print "doing one"
    do_work(*arguments)

def do_many(x, y, zs):
    map(do_one, [(x, y, z) for z in zs])

def do_many_pooled(x, y, zs):
    pool = Pool(2)
    pool.map(do_one, [(x, y, z) for z in zs])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def main():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    zs = range(10)
    print "doing many"
    do_many(x, y, zs)
    print "doing many pooled"
    do_many_pooled(x, y, zs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The real program does a lot of database requests, computations using numpy and storing results back into a database.
In the real program, the program exits with an error, before printing "doing one", when used with the pooled version, but runs fine using the non-pooled version.

Does anyone know, how to read the Traceback correctly and/or can tell me, what possibly can cause this Exception?

Comment: maybe you can use [map_async](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async) and use [AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) `get` method to reraise the exception and you'll find more information?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  Python 2.7.what?

Comment: @tobias_k yes, i am 100% sure. As stated in the text, the error cannot be reproduced by this example and I do not know what it takes to reproduce the error with a minimal example.

Comment: @jszakmeister The Python Version is 2.7.5

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it looks like `put` is being clobbered an set to None from this part of
the traceback:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
   put(task)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Looking at the Python source, `Pool.__init__()` is setting up `_task_handler`
which will make a call to `_handle_tasks` and is providing the arguments for
said call:

```
self._task_handler = threading.Thread(
    target=Pool._handle_tasks,
    args=(self._taskqueue, self._quick_put, self._outqueue, self._pool)
    )
```

If you look at `_handle_tasks`, then you see that `self._quick_put` is what ends
up being the `put` variable:

```
@staticmethod
def _handle_tasks(taskqueue, put, outqueue, pool, cache):
    thread = threading.current_thread()

    for taskseq, set_length in iter(taskqueue.get, None):
        i = -1
        for i, task in enumerate(taskseq):
            if thread._state:
                debug('task handler found thread._state != RUN')
                break
            try:
                put(task)
            except Exception as e:
                job, ind = task[:2]
                try:
                    cache[job]._set(ind, (False, e))
                except KeyError:
                    pass
        else:
            if set_length:
                debug('doing set_length()')
                set_length(i+1)
            continue
        break
    else:
        debug('task handler got sentinel')
```

Moreover, you can see that all exceptions are being caught here and tucked away
for reporting later.  But, if you head back to Python 2.7.6, you'll see this:

```
@staticmethod
def _handle_tasks(taskqueue, put, outqueue, pool):
    thread = threading.current_thread()

    for taskseq, set_length in iter(taskqueue.get, None):
        i = -1
        for i, task in enumerate(taskseq):
            if thread._state:
                debug('task handler found thread._state != RUN')
                break
            try:
                put(task)
            except IOError:
                debug('could not put task on queue')
                break
        else:
            if set_length:
                debug('doing set_length()')
                set_length(i+1)
            continue
        break
    else:
        debug('task handler got sentinel')
```

Notice here that a `TypeError` could escape.  It turns out that this was fixed
as a result of bug [#19425](http://bugs.python.org/issue19425).  Oddly, it was
claimed that this was not an issue in Python 2.7, but the changeset was still
backported.

At any rate, in either case, `put()` should be a known value, and there doesn't
appear to be any way to set `put` in this code.  So, to me, it smells like a bug
in Python.  Any chance you can run the same code under a newer version of
Python?

*Some other useful information*

A quick Google search returns some interesting results too:

- Python bug [#9755](http://bugs.python.org/issue9775) - Similar but different
  stack trace.
- Python bug [#15881](http://bugs.python.org/issue15881) - Similar to the above,
  but a slightly different stack trace too.

Both are issues where cleanup was affecting module state and causing things to
fail with a "'NoneType' object is not callable" exception.

Other, somewhat related bugs have existed in Python too.  At one point you could
encounter a similar exception with the use of daemon threads and exiting the
main thread of your application.  I forget which version that was fixed in.  I
just wanted to show that this kind of problem isn't unheard of and is a bug in
Python.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try that tomorrow and keep you updated with my results. Edit: Thinking about this, why did the code run successfully earlier then? As far as I know, it was all python 2.7.x, where I (from home) don't know x, but I am pretty sure that x didn't change.

Comment: It's hard to say.  Depending on how things are being run, torn down, etc., you may be running into a situation where something racy is happening (e.g., something is being garbage collected out from under you).  The stacktrace is definitely odd, which is why it's such a mystery. :-(

Comment: I should add, if I were debugging this, I'd start by printing out the value of put before calling it.  Yes, that would mean modifying the installed Python code, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: @Nras where you able to try a newer version Python?

Comment: Sorry, I had to work on something more critical today. Will most likely be able to do it tomorrow. I am for sure still interested in solving this problem.

Comment: No problem.  I was just wondering since you were able to dig up the version number.

Comment: Yep the version number is 2.7.5

Comment: Still no time, but this looks promising (also the provided links to similar problems). Since the bounty expires soon, I gave it to you.

Comment: That wasn't necessary--I don't do this for the points--but thank you.  If you do get a chance to try, I think it's worth coming back to note whether it worked better or not.  Thanks again!